# Gather arrays of different sizes using MPI_Allgather

Tags: fortran, mpi

`MPI_Allgather` seems to assume that all arrays to be gathered from different processes are of the the same size. However, in my case, the arrays to be gathered are of different size in different processes. For this case, what is the proper subroutine to use?
Is it `MPI_Allgatherv`?

Comment: I tested it out: `MPI_Allgatherv` is exactly what I need to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the correct function is `MPI_Allgatherv`.